# Ubuntu 12.04 - python 3.2 - pygame

Tags: python3

I have Ubuntu 12.04.
In terminal I start Python 2.7 and then import Pygame and it works.
In terminal when I start Python 3.2 and try to import Pygame it says it can't find Pygame.
What is happening?

Comment: That probably means that pygame is written in python 2.7 and does not work on python 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu currently only has Pygame for Python2. You can't use it with Python3.